# BFS visit in Prolog, why this program don't work?

Tags: prolog

I have take this program that implement BFS visit algorithm from Ivan Bratko book: "Programming for Artificial Intelligence".

It's logic is pretty clear form me (I have commented the lines of code with its meaning) but don't work.

My code is:

```
s(a, b).
s(b, c).
s(c, d).
s(a, d).

% GOAL: il raggiungimento del nodo d:
goal(d).


/* solve(Start, Solution): Solution is a path (in reverse order) from Start to a goal it is TRUE
   if it is TRUE breadthfirst(Paths, Solution) (it is TRUE if some path from a candidate set of paths Paths
   can be extended to a goal nod. Solution is such an extended path
*/
solve(Start, Solution) :- breadthfirst([[Start]], Solution).

/* breadthfirst([Path1, Path2, ...], Solution) it is TRUE if:
   Solution is an extension to a goal of one of the paths in the Paths list of candidates paths

   SET CANDIDATES PATH RAPPRESENTATIONS: The set will be represented as a list of paths, and each path will
   be a list of nodes in the inverse order; that is, the head will be the most recently generated node, and
   the last element of the list will be the start node of the search
*/

/* BASE CASE: If the HEAD of the FIRST PATH (in Paths list) is a GOAL then this path is a Solution of the problem
*/
breadthfirst([[Node|Path]|_], [Node|Path]) :- goal(Node).


/* GENERAL CASE: Otherwise (if the head of the first path is not a goal node) remove the first path from the
   candidates set and generate the set of all possible one-step extensions of this paths, add this set of
   extension at the end of the candidate set, and execute breath-first search on this updated set
*/
breadthfirst([Path|Paths], Solution) :- 
                /* Remove the first path from the Paths list and extends it (generate the set of 
                                   all possible one-step extensions of this paths that is NewPaths list */          
                extend(Path, NewPaths),

                                /* Paths1 = [Paths|NewPaths] */                 
                conc(Paths, NewPaths, Paths1),
                /* Execute BFS on Paths1 */
                breadthfirst(Paths1, Solution).

/* extended/2 predicate take a Path that is a list of node and generate the set of all possible one-step 
   extensions of this paths
*/
extend([Node|Path], NewPaths) :- bagof([NewNode, Node|Path],
                                       (s(Node, NewNode), not member(NewNode,[Node|Path]) ),
                                       NewPaths),
                                 !.

extend(Path, []).              % bagof failed: Node has no successor

conc([],L,L).

conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :- conc(L1,L2,L3).
```

The problem is that when I try to execute a query it always respond me with FALSE (also if exist a path from a start node X to another note Y)

For example (doing a trace of the situation) I have that:

```
[trace]  ?- solve(a,Solution).
   Call: (6) solve(a, _G367) ? creep
   Call: (7) breadthfirst([[a]], _G367) ? creep
   Call: (8) goal(a) ? creep
   Fail: (8) goal(a) ? creep
   Redo: (7) breadthfirst([[a]], _G367) ? creep
   Call: (8) extend([a], _G443) ? creep
   Exit: (8) extend([a], []) ? creep
   Call: (8) conc([], [], _G444) ? creep
   Exit: (8) conc([], [], []) ? creep
   Call: (8) breadthfirst([], _G367) ? creep
   Fail: (8) breadthfirst([], _G367) ? creep
   Fail: (7) breadthfirst([[a]], _G367) ? creep
   Fail: (6) solve(a, _G367) ? creep
false.
```

As you can see the problem seems occur when it try to extend the current node that is not a goal node (in this case a). Extend a node mean delete the first path from the head of Paths list (the list of candidates paths), and since the elements in this path, create a new list named NewPath containing all the one-step neighbors nodes of these nodes.

Then, using the **conc/2** predicate it builds a  new **Paths1** list of candidates path putting at the end of the **Paths** list (the old list of candidates paths without the head) the **NewPaths** list

Then execute breadthfirst on this new list (**Paths1**)

The problem seems occur when it try to extend the current node because seems the **extends/2** predicate don't work well (in fact the NewPath apper void):

```
extend([Node|Path], NewPaths) :- bagof([NewNode, Node|Path],
                                       (s(Node, NewNode), not member(NewNode,[Node|Path]) ),
                                       NewPaths),
                                 !.
```

For more information I obtain the following error message when I consult my program:

```
[debug]  ?- consult(bfs).
ERROR: /home/andrea/Documenti/prolog/lezione10/bfs.pl:47:62: Syntax error: Operator expected
Warning: /home/andrea/Documenti/prolog/lezione10/bfs.pl:51:
    Singleton variables: [Path]
% bfs compiled 0.00 sec, 160 bytes
true.
```

Why? Do you have some idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on line 47

```
not member(NewNode,[Node|Path])
```

is invalid syntax. it must be either

```
\+ member(NewNode,[Node|Path])
```

or

```
not( member(NewNode,[Node|Path]) )
```